# @XmlSeeAlso Inheritance

Tags: spring, jaxb

First, I am a newbie in the JAXB and Spring world so if I missed something very obvious I would really appreciate it if someone can point it out instead of not replying. :) I tried searching for a solution here but could not find a good answer.

I have a bunch of subclass DTO's(say A1, A2, A3) which inherit from the same abstract class A. I want the result of my rest query to return a list of the subclass type. I have the following class to represent the result

```
@XmlRootElement(name="result")
@XmlSeeAlso({A1.class, A2.class, A3.class})
public class AResult<T> 
{
...
}
```

Since AResult is generic I would like the @XmlSeeAlso to also be generic and just write something like

```
@XmlSeeAlso({(subclasses of A.class})
```

But I do not think that is possible with JAXB from the research I did on this site and elsewhere.

1. Since we use the annotation-driven tag in the config, it automatically uses the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter class. This message converter creates the JaxbContext using the classes defined in @XmlSeeAlso among others. The createMarshaller and getContext methods are immutable in a superclass.
2. Because of point 1, I can not write a class where I can check if a class is a subclass of class A and then add it to the JaxbContext. I cannot use a custom Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter or a custom Marshaller.

How do I get around this? BTW, we are using Spring version 3.1.3

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Donal. Here is how I got around this issue: 1. Create a CustomJaxb2RootElementMessageConverter that extends HttpMessageConverter. 2. In my custom class pass the context as a path and include jaxb.index files in those packages. 3. Changed the messageConverters for AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter and RequestMappingHandlerAdapter to use my Custom class.

Answer (score 2):

JAXB doesn't scan your classpath for classes that *might* just happen to be subclasses of `AResult` (that would be rather slow!) but rather relies on the [context](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) knowing about all the classes that it might ever have to create instances of. All the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation does is extend the context with the additional classes listed.

However, there are a number of other approaches. For example, you could create a class marked with [`@XmlRegistry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRegistry.html) that knows how to make the subclasses that you care about. Or you could experiment with using [`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html). Alas, I've only ever progressed as far as using the `@XmlSeeAlso`-based approach in my own code, so I can't comment really from experience.